# Is there a name for permutations of numbers 1 to n such that there is no case where $i\to j$ and $j\to i?$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Is there a name for permutations of numbers $1$ to $n$ such that there is no case where $i\to j$ and $j\to i?$

Such permutations would have to be derangements and would include circular shifts other than shifts of length $n/2$ when $n$ is even.  The obvious follow-up question would be that if there is a name for these permutations, is there a way of determining or estimating how many there are for a given value of $n$?

Comment: So, your conditions does not assume $i\neq j?$ A permutation would have this property if and only if its square would be a derangement. Don't know a name.

Comment: Clarification requested: "Such permutations would have to be derangements" : why?  Do you mean that you are imposing the additional constraint that the permutation is a derangement?

Comment: @user2661923 I assumed that meant the condition restricted cases when $i=j,$ although I did ask for clarification.

Comment: A permutation with no transpositions?

Comment: @RandyMarsh It also includes no fixed points, apparently.

Comment: Please, in the future: Don't only *only* ask the question in the title. More on these best practices for this site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/6509).

Comment: Given a derangement, $\pi$ we can find $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^2=\pi$ if and only if the number of orbits of even order $2k$ is even for each even $2k\leq n.$ But there will often be many such $\sigma.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call these "permutations with no fixed points or transpositions." They have their own OEIS entry, https://oeis.org/A038205, and are referred to as "derangements of $n$ where minimal cycle size is at least $3$".

Using the method of exponential generating functions, the number of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no fixed points or transpositions is
$$
n![x^n]\exp\left(-\log(1-x)-x-x^2/2\right)=n![x^n] \frac{e^{-x-x^2/2}}{1-x}
$$
The notation $[x^n]f(x)$ means "the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series $f(x)$". Here is a Wolfram Alpha query that can evaluate this expression: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=n%21*SeriesCoefficient%5Be%5E%28-x-x%5E2%2F2%29%2F%281-x%29%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D+where+n+%3D+4. This formula also appears at the OEIS page.

Let me try to give a crude estimate for the number of such permutations, without giving any proof.

It is well-known that the number of fixed points of a permutation is approximately Poisson distributed with parameter $1$. Similarly, the number of transpositions is approximately Poisson with parameter $1/2$. These two variables are dependent, because if $X_1$ is the number of fixed points, and $X_2$ the number of transpositions, then the constraint $X_1+2X_2\le n$ always holds. However, I will assert that these two are "approximately independent" (whatever the hell that means), and conclude the expected number of combined fixed points and transpositions, $X_1+X_2$, is approximately Poisson with parameter $1+1/2=3/2$. Therefore,
$$
P(X_1+X_2=0)\approx P(\text{Poisson}(3/2)=0)=e^{-3/2}.
$$
This suggests that the number of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no fixed points or transpositions is approximately $$e^{-3/2}\cdot n!\,.$$ Indeed, this asymptotic formula appears on the OEIS page, so my hand-waiving actually lead to a correct result.